# how to match a word with a list of tubles

Tags: list, tuples, match

i am trying to find a word in a list of tuples. I tried the following code

```
 keywords_adera = [('athletes', 0.4235), ('scrimmages', 0.3895),('athlete', 0.379),('sport', 0.3714),('soccer', 0.3699)]
b_adera='athletes'
if b_adera in keywords_adera2:
    print('macrious4')
```

the code does not give any output. Any suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You have to iterate over a list keywords_adera
Then you check if your searched word is in current tuple

```
for t in lst:
    if word in t:
        print('found')
```

Answer (score 1):

The tuple is in list you need to match entier tuple with
Value for if statement to be true

```
 keywords_adera = [('athletes', 0.4235), ('scrimmages', 0.3895), 
 ('athlete', 0.379),('sport', 0.3714),('soccer', 0.3699)]
  b_adera=('athletes',0.4235)
  if b_adera in keywords_adera:
      print('macrious4')
```

Else you would need to iterate over list or specify which index in list